# .htaccess Extended Subdomain URL Rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

*I want to preserve domain.com/whatever & www.domain.com/whatever for my main application site, just as a precursor to the following.*

For my users, I have my app set up for their home pages to be username.domain.com. This is great, and shows their page, but the problem I am having is when I try handle username.domain.com/one, username.domain.com/one/two, username.domain.com/one/two/three

Here's currently what I have that successfully sends subdomains to u.php

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  u.php
```

I don't need that changed (it works). What I need now is:

1. username.domain.com is written to u.php (currently working great using above expression)
2. username.domain.com/one is written to a.php?request=one
3. username.domain.com/one/two is written to s.php?request=one&ident=two

## Edit

Here is some of the expressions that worked before I tweaked the app to run off of user subdomains, just to help:

```
    RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/?$ a.php?request=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /s.php?request=$1&ident=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^u/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /s.php?user=$1&request=$2&ident=$3 [L]
```

## Please Remember

That my problem currently is that everything is going to user.domain.com/one is not being rewritten. It is still going to u.php, when i want it to go to s.php?request=$1

**Thanks again for the help!**

Comment: does your sub-domain goes to a different folder than the www domain?

Comment: Please post the code that 'doesn't seem to work'.

Comment: Ok - updated. Please re-read it, as I edited the whole thing to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is actually saying "whatever it is, send it to u.php":

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  u.php
```

One problem you have here is the order in which you've put the expressions. Because of your [L] flag... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/?$ a.php?request=$1 [L] ## <- would match one/two/three and would stop the script from continuing because of the [L] flag.
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /s.php?request=$1&ident=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /s.php?user=$1&request=$2&ident=$3 [L]
```

**Probable solution**

I have concatenated all your intentions into one match expression, I hope it works for you...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)?/?([a-z\-]+)?/?([a-z\-]+)?/?$  u.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) u.php [L]
```

This code would send you some empty parameters... which you should you check on in your PHP code.

If you really don't want that you can always split your code...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/?$  u.php?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/?$  u.php?first=$1&second=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/?$  u.php?first=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) u.php [L]
```

Notice the order of the expressions. The third expression would actually match one/two/three.

I am just using [a-z-] here. Looking at your own code I figure you know how to add support for digits or uppercase characters.